# PHP - MySql Array

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, eclipse

I am new to PHP and I am having trouble solving this: I have an array (PHP) that looks like this

```
"tandemArray":["English", "German"]
```

As seen in my LogCat (Eclipse, I return the array to the Android client and log it in Eclipse). I want to query the database with a string similar to:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT id 
            FROM my_users 
            WHERE // some code
            AND Tandem_Tongue IN ("English", "German"); // The tandemArray
```

I've tried different approaches but without success. For instance:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT id 
            FROM my_users 
            WHERE // some code
            AND Tandem_Tongue IN ("' . implode('","', $tandemArray) . '")';
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: what exactly would you like to do?

Comment: Well, you've got mismatching quotes and double-quotes in your shown approach; try reversing the ' and " to be like this: `AND Tandem_Tongue IN ('" . implode("','", $tandemArray) . "')";`

Comment: Thanks!! It worked now! I would select your answer as correct, but it is a comment, and I do not know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code uses mismatching quotes and double-quotes in your shown approach; try reversing the ' and " to be like this:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT id"
    . " FROM my_users"
    . " WHERE 1=1" // using an actual WHERE-clause
    . " AND Tandem_Tongue IN ('" . implode("','", $tandemArray) . "')";
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is provided by ChrisForrence:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT id 
        FROM my_users 
        WHERE // some code
        AND Tandem_Tongue IN ('" . implode("','", $tandemArray) . "')';
```

The problem was in quotes mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Not positive but I think you've mismatched the quotes and periods in your example.  Should be more like:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT id 
        FROM my_users 
        WHERE // some code
        AND Tandem_Tongue IN (".implode("','",$tandemArray).")';
```

I just used single quotes around the array elements since that is usually easier for me to decipher in mysql queries.  Eg. 'English', 'German'  You'll need to adjust if you need double quotes.

Comment: My answer differs from ChrisForence's because I don't start the array off with a single quote.  I think the implode statement will already put one at the beginning for you.

Comment: Careful; it doesn't! It'd be nice if it did, though, and you can write a helper method that takes care of that for you